# If I'm dependent on a slow service, how do I avoid spending processor time waiting for it?

Tags: java, multithreading, service, architecture

So I'm working with code a little like this:

```
public void callSlowService(List<Object> objectsToCallFor) {
    objectsToCallFor
        .parallelStream()
        .forEach(object -> slowService.call(object))
}
```

Where slowService.call takes ~100-500ms

The problem is, I can parallelize all I want, but at the end of the day I'm still locking a thread for 500ms just waiting around, and my CPUs have other things they could be doing for other threads.

Assuming that I can't change this other service whatsoever (I can't), is there some other design I could use on my side which frees my CPUs do other things while waiting for a response from slowService?

Comment: If whatever you're calling to access the service is sanely written, you are *blocking,* not 'spending processor time'.

Comment: Yeah I really wouldn't worry about a thread that is waiting.  Threads are lightweight (unlike processes) and you can have thousands of them before a VM chokes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

However, you **can** mitigate the problem. Use one new thread that is fed through a `BlockingQueue` of `List<Object> objectsToCallFor` and feeds another queue with the results as they arrive.

You will still wait the required time for the results but at least your main processing will continue meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you wanna make this method asynchronous. If you don't need results and you want to skip error handling you may want to launch code in new thread.
Like:

```
public void callSlowService(final List<Object> objectsToCallFor) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        objectsToCallFor
            .parallelStream()
            .forEach(object -> slowService.call(object));
    }).start();
}
```

Another(better) way - using ThreadPool. You shoulc be carefull with using parallelStream() -> then you will be using shared ForkJoinPool that can affect performance of your application. It is more safety to use old good cached thread pool, or any other threadpool implementation depends of project needs.

```
public ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public void callSlowService(final List<Object> objectsToCallFor) {
    for (Object obj : objectsToCallFor) {
        executor.submit(() -> {
            objectsToCallFor
                .parallelStream()
                .forEach(object -> slowService.call(object));
        });
    }
}
```

In fact, there are few other way to make similar in more beautiful way, but this should works also.